# return a JavaScript result (js file) to Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

How to return a JavaScript result (js file) to Angular 7 and use it In Javascript all the steps are performed simultaneously but I want the result to come back and then run Angular. I used the following code, but it's not true:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            sign(); // this is in JS file
            setTimeout(() => resolve(opSignature), 7000); // opSignature is result of sign()
          }).then(
              result => {
                this.saveChallenge(result); // call angular method
              }
          );
```

I need to return the value in my js file and then use this result in Angular In JavaScript all steps are executed sequentially and do not allow the previous steps to be completed and go to the next step My problem is that the top line result still does not return to the next line that is Angular and now the top line result is needed. sign() is method in javascript file and this.saveChallenge(result); is angular 7

angular :

```
this._loginService.saveSignature(opSign)
        .pipe(map(response =>
          this.goToProcess(opSign)
        ))
        .subscribe( );
```

js file:

```
function sign() {
// my code ...
}
```

Comment: Unable to understand the question. Please explain in more details

Comment: I have an external js file that I call in Angular
And I need to pass the result to a Angular method .
How is this operation to do?
Can I use the result of the JS method to pass it to Angular, and not go to Angular before filling this value?

Comment: can you please provide working demo? It is difficult to understand what you are expecting.

Comment: do you have the declaration file for the external js lib that you're using?

Answer (score 1):

i resolve this problem . 
i call angular method in js file . 
in js file:

```
window.angularComponentReference.zone.run(() => { window.angularComponentReference.loadAngularFunction(); });
```

in angular :

```
    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
      }
    ngOnInit() {
        window['angularComponentReference'] = { component: this, zone: this.ngZone, loadAngularFunction: () => this.angularFunctionCalled(), };

 private angularFunctionCalled() {
    ....
  }
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Can it be modified to actually pass a parameter? I tried and the value gets lost in the middle..

Comment: i think you can pass parameter but another solution. i dont think lost value ,I have to try

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to pass parameters. By removing the arrow (which is not recognized by IE, by the way), it becomes clear:

In index.html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function callAngularFunction(param) {
      window.angularComponentReference.zone.run(function() { return window.angularComponentReference.loadAngularFunction(param); });
    }
  </script>
```

Then, in the .ts file:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    window['angularComponentReference'] = { component: this, zone: this.ngZone, loadAngularFunction: (param) => this.angularFunctionCalled(param) };
    ...
  }
  angularFunctionCalled(param) {
    ...
  }
```